# What is the meaning of "multiple" parameter in Seaborn's kdeplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, kdeplot

I am trying to understand the meaning of `multiple` parameter in Seaborn's [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html). Below is taken from its documentation,

> multiple{{“layer”, “stack”, “fill”}}
>
> Method for drawing multiple elements when semantic mapping creates subsets. Only relevant with univariate data.

However it doesn't help much and their plots looks very different. I would appreciate it if someone can elaborate them more.

Here are the plots created with setting `multiple` to `layer`, `stack` and `fill` respectively,

```
sns.displot(data=bg_vs_non_bg, multiple="layer", x="Value", hue="ClassName", kind="kde", col="Modality", log_scale=True, fill=True)
```

[image: multiple="layer"]

```
sns.displot(data=bg_vs_non_bg, multiple="stack", x="Value", hue="ClassName", kind="kde", col="Modality", log_scale=True)
```

[image: multiple="stack"]

```
sns.displot(data=bg_vs_non_bg, multiple="fill", x="Value", hue="ClassName", kind="kde", col="Modality", log_scale=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it like this:

| Option | Meaning | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `layer` | Original density | The densities are overlaid on each other, so the *y*-value just represents the original density of each curve. |
| `stack` | Stacked density | The densities are stacked on each other, so the *y*-value represents the stacked sum of the densities, i.e, the second curve's *y*-value is the sum of the first and second densities. |
| `fill` | Proportional density | The densities are normalized to sum to 1, so the *y*-value represents the proportional density of each curve relative to the others. |

Or in visual form:

[image: visual comparison]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a reference for this ?

Comment: @tdy  You left out `common_norm=` which plays an essential role in this explanation.

Comment: @JohanC Hmm does it? I thought `common_norm` changes the way each density is calculated, but the meaning of `multiple` stays the same either way.

Comment: @Melike I couldn't find a (detailed) explanation in the docs either.

Comment: For example, with `multiple='stack'` you only get the cumulative density when `common_norm=True` (the default). With `common_norm=False` you'd get N times the density (with N the number of hue values).  The difference is especially striking with unbalanced data sets.  With `multiple='layer'` you only get the original density when `common_norm=False`, otherwise you'll see the densities scaled down depending on the relative size of each hue group.

Comment: Nice answer. My only nit is that "cumulative density" is a little confusing because that term is overloaded and would usually mean a cumulation of the density along the x axis.

Comment: @mwaskom Ah, good point. I just changed it to "stacked density." That's somewhat circular, but not sure if there's a better way to describe it unambiguously.